# Creating and Plotting a Confusion Matrix from a Plain Matrix

Tags: plotting

Using [ClassifierMeasurementsObject](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurementsObject.html) you can plot nice ConfusionMatrix:

[image]

**But how to mimic this matrix plot from a plain Matrix?**

In other terms, from

```
M={{2,0},{1,1}}
k={"A","B"}
```

I would like to reproduce the previous plot.

So far I tried:

```
MatrixPlot[M,Frame->True,
             FrameLabel->{"actual","predicted"},
             ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

but a lot of things are missing.

The most important are:

- numbers in the plot
- tick labels (note that they are rotated which is important as I have long names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = {{2, 0}, {1, 1}};
k = {"A", "B"};
MatrixPlot[m, ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"actual", "predicted"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, k], 
    MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, Total@Transpose@m]}, 
   {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, Total[m]], 
    MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, k]}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 16], #2 - 1/2] &, Transpose@Reverse@m, {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this. I included it in the package ["ROCFunctions.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/ROCFunctions.m); see this [link](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/commit/67aef4d2f9b4f88a52eb79bd7de95613c1aa7aa2#diff-25fe888e9ecc5a893349ca9a50a6bb1c) .

Comment: Awesome! Thank you (I just added a Rotate[#,Pi/2] for upper tick labels)